# Quadratic error function

Tags: machine-learning

I have read some articles which mention "Quadratic" error function several times. I know the form and plot of the error function, but not sure about "Quadratic" error function.

Could someone, please explain it to me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the source so we know the context in which the term quadratic is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it means proportional to the square of something.  Traditional regression, for example, is also known as OLS, or Ordinary Least Squares, which is a quadratic loss function.

Quadratic loss functions have a natural value, since the central limit theorem makes many random models converge on a normal distribution, an then the only two parameters are the mean and the variance, the latter of which is quadratic.

Usually, when you see the term quadratic, it is referring to - or allowing - generalization to more than one dimension.  if $x$ is a vector, and $A$ is a matrix, and they conform, then $x'Ax$ is a generalized 'quadratic form'.

Comment: Instead of the argument in the second paragraph, you could say minimizing the sum of squared errors equals maximizing the likelihood under the normal distribution. I think this is a more sensible argument than pointing out that variance is quadratic.